# error in my procedure MySQL find value INT in all tables database

Tags: mysql, sql, procedure

I want find a number of UserId from all tables  `call searchUser(3,'UserId')`
**error:**   0  14:30:14    call searchUser(3,'UserId') Error Code: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NULL' at line 1

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE `searchUser`( in_search int(11),in_column_name varchar(50) )
    READS SQL DATA
BEGIN
    DECLARE trunc_cmd VARCHAR(50);
    DECLARE searchUserId int (11);
    DECLARE db,tbl,clmn CHAR(50);

   DECLARE done INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE COUNTER INT;


    DECLARE table_cur CURSOR FOR


    SELECT concat('SELECT COUNT(*) INTO @CNT_VALUE FROM `',table_name,'` WHERE `', in_column_name,'` = "',in_search,'"') ,table_name,column_name FROM information_schema.`COLUMNS` WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'comments' and column_name=in_column_name ;

    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done=1;

    PREPARE trunc_cmd FROM "TRUNCATE TABLE temp_details;";
    EXECUTE trunc_cmd ; 
    OPEN table_cur;

table_loop:LOOP
        FETCH table_cur INTO db, tbl, clmn;


    SET @searchUserId = searchUserId;
    SELECT  searchUserId;
    PREPARE searchUserId FROM @searchUserId;
    EXECUTE searchUserId;

    SET COUNTER = @CNT_VALUE;
    SELECT COUNTER;

    IF COUNTER>0 THEN

        INSERT INTO temp_details VALUES(db,tbl,clmn);
    END IF;

        IF done=1 THEN
            LEAVE table_loop;
        END IF;

END LOOP;
CLOSE table_cur;
SELECT * FROM temp_details;
    END
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem must be due to:

```
DECLARE searchUserId int (11);
```

and:

```
SET @searchUserId = searchUserId;
SELECT  searchUserId;
PREPARE searchUserId FROM @searchUserId;
EXECUTE searchUserId;
```

I assume that you are thinking `searchUserId` has a value. But nowhere in the code you assigned a value to it. By default it is a `NULL`. And hence the statement `EXECUTE searchUserId` is translate to `EXECUTE NULL`. This caused the error you specified.

To resolve it, you should first assign a proper value to the `searchUserId` variable declared.

BTW, why are you using the same variable name `searchUserId` for a local variable, global variable, and statement alias? It would confuse the readers of the program and hence is not advised to practice.

Comment: 0 09:10:01 call searchUserNOT_OK(3, 'UserId') Error Code: 1328. Incorrect number of FETCH variables


I use
 SET @searchUserId = in_search;
    SELECT  searchUserId;
    PREPARE searchUserId FROM @searchUserId;
    EXECUTE searchUserId;

Comment: I'm trying to make a similar solution which I searched in google but for searching string in all tables not searching int in all tables

Answer (score 0):

I guess problem lies in this statement-creation-statement:

```
SELECT concat('SELECT COUNT(*) INTO @CNT_VALUE FROM `',table_name,'` WHERE `', in_column_name,'` = "',in_search,'"') ,table_name,column_name FROM information_schema.`COLUMNS` WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'comments' and column_name=in_column_name ;
```

Please execute the statement standalone and see what you get.

Comment: statement i OK. I use new procedure and show table_name from schema comments and column_name = UserId

Comment: but if I use call new_procedure(3,'UserId')  show me only column UserId and tables but this statement dont use in_search = in_column_name